# Is it hard to transplant my ios app to android app?

Tags: android, ios, transplant

I have some ios app want to achieve to deploy to the android play market, is it hard to do it?
I know how to develop object c program, but not familiar with the android coding. Any suggestion would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I reality you cannot  convert ios app which is written in objective c to an Android app.

If it  is using html and JS only the it will be easier ,other wise it is better to start with java and xml for android from [here](http://developer.android.com/about/start.html) and if you know the logic of your app  well you can implement if quite easily.